# Creating form widgets based on instance values

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
VARIABLE_CHOICES = (
    ('bool', 'On/Off'),
    ('date', 'Date'),
    ('float', 'Number'),
    ('text', 'Text'),
)

class LetterVariable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=VARIABLE_CHOICES)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to create a form that when I pass it an instance of `LetterVariable` from the db it will create the corrosponding widget for `data` bassed upon `type`.

Any ideas how I might do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class LetterVariableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LetterVariableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.instance:
           raise Exception('You forgot the instance!');

        if self.instance.type == 'something':
            self.fields['data'].widget = forms.SomeWidget()
```

Comment: Cheers! Any chance you can tell me how can I throw an error if an instance is not passed?

Comment: See update, but remember that that's not something and end-user should ever see. You might want to provide a better message or a more appropriate exception type, but you're code should ensure that it is then never raised.

Comment: Just wanted to raise it for development reasons