# Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'DecimalField' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: django, django-forms

following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096189/creating-form-widgets-based-on-instance-values/8097124#8097124). I have the following:

models.py

```
VARIABLE_CHOICES = (
    ('bool', 'On/Off'),
    ('date', 'Date'),
    ('float', 'Number'),
    ('text', 'Text'),
)

class Variable(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=VARIABLE_CHOICES, default=2)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class VariableForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VariableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance:
            if self.instance.type == 'bool':
                self.fields['data'].widget = BooleanField()
            if self.instance.type == 'date':
                self.fields['data'].widget = DateField()
            if self.instance.type == 'float':
                self.fields['data'].widget = DecimalField()
            if self.instance.type == 'text':
                self.fields['data'].widget = TextInput()
            self.fields['data'].label = self.instance.name
```

views.py

```
def template_variables_view(request,tID):
    ...
    templateVariables = Variable.objects.filter(template=template)
    lvForm = []
    for ltVars in templateVariables:
        lvForm.append(VariableForm(instance=ltVars))
```

and I am cycling through the forms in lvForm like so in the template:

```
{% for lo in ltvForm %}
    {% for field in lo %}
        <td>{{ field.label }}:</td><td>{{ field }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I keep getting the error `Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'DecimalField' object has no attribute 'attrs'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the data field's widget to a field, for some reason. You should just be setting the field.

```
if self.instance.type == 'bool':
    self.fields['data'] = BooleanField()
```

etc.

Comment: +1 Except for the TextInput at the end. @Sevenearths there are fields and widgets.. take note which is which.

Comment: If you're changing the entire field, though, bear in mind that this will undo things like the field's label, required or not status, help_text etc. You must redeclare those on the new field if necessary, e.g. `BooleanField(label='Data Item', required=False, help_text='Add some data here')`.

Comment: and also I apperently need to re-do the id' as well (because they will all be the same) with `lvForm.append(VariableForm(instance=ltVars,auto_id=ltVars.id+'%s'))`