# Django - custom widget - why does Django think I don't have 'attrs'?

Tags: django, django-widget

*EDIT: Using Django 1.3*

I've built a Custom Widget to educate myself but I can't get past a problem where when the page is fetched Django says that:

```
'FooTestWidget' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

I don't want to use the 'attrs' argument and I've set it to default to None (also tried an empty dictionary, eg {}) so I'm confused about why Django is complaining.

**widgets.py**

```
class FooTestWidget(Widget):
    """
    A very silly widget to test I can do anything
    """
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        pass

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        tpl = Template(u"""<h1>This is here instead of a CharField</h1>""")
        return mark_safe(tpl.substitute(colour=value))
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
                'name_family': FooTestWidget,
        }

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserAdminForm
```

**model.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='USE_ID')
    name_given = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='USE_NAME_GIVEN')
    name_family = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='USE_NAME_FAMILY')
```

---

**WORKING VERSION AFTER HELP FROM DANIEL**

Here's a working version of widgets.py after taking on board what Daniel explained in his answer and then me making one or two other small changes (which weren't assocated with the problem described here but which stopped it working as it should). This version now works as I expected it to:

```
from datetime import date
import re

from django.forms.widgets import Widget, Select
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms import widgets
from django.template.base import Template

__all__ = ('FooTestWidget',)

RE_DATE = re.compile(r'(\d{4})-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)$')

class FooTestWidget(Widget):
    """
    A very silly widget to test I can do anything
    """
    #def __init__(self, attrs={}):
    #    pass

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        sout = u"""<h1>This is here instead of a CharField</h1>"""
        return mark_safe(sout)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099179/caught-attributeerror-while-rendering-decimalfield-object-has-no-attribute-a

Comment: @catherine - Thanks for your comment. I agree the error message is the same but it's not really the same situation (is it ?). I mean there's not a custom widget involved and the op seems to have confused fields and widgets ? I'm happy to be corrected but as far as I can see the text of the error message is the only thing that connects the two ? Thanks again.

Comment: yes it's not the same. I just want you to know why that error occur. And I think you got that error because you put it wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is you've overridden `__init__` with a method that does nothing. Since you don't even call the superclass method, none of the setup that Django is expecting will happen: including setting the `attrs` parameter to the `self.attrs` attribute.

Basically, if you really must override `__init__`, then at least call `super(FooTestWidget, self).__init__(attrs)` there somewhere. But, if you're not doing anything special in that method, best not to override it at all and let the super method be used automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much. This has allowed me to get it working (I've put the working version in the editted question above for the sake of future searchers). As you may have guessed I've been mucking around trying a lot of things and the __init__ containing only 'pass' was one of those iterations which I then forgot about ! Thanks again, much appreciated.